# Ubuntu desktop is empty

Tags: xubuntu

I have downloaded this image https://bitnami.com/stack/edx/virtual-machine
and installed it in virtual box

Then I executed the following

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
set display=:0
ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended
sudo apt-get install (recommended driver file)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot

startx
```

However the desktop is empty, what can I do know? how do I open a browser? network settings?

http://screencast.com/t/HXmBaHaxS1

Comment: That image is not Ubuntu, it is some kind of spin. If you want Ubuntu, get it here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, a Linux desktop OS is the same as a Linux server OS, the only difference really is the preconfigured GUI.  Under the GUI it is still a Linux server.  The only reason Linux differentiates the two is because of the preconfigured GUI.  If you install a Linux desktop OS, you can still do all the things you do with a Linux server OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you initially installed a server OS, so there are no GUI programs installed on one of those.  So, now that you have installed a GUI desktop, you need to install GUI programs.

So to start you will want to I guess install Firefox:

```
CTRL+ALT+T
```

Opens terminal
then type:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

And you will have a browser, then you can search for the commands to install whatever else you would like.

Comment: I looked up Bitnami, and to be honest, I am not sure this will work, so What I want to ask if it does not work is:  Is there a particular reason you want to use Bitnami over an install of Ubuntu, besides the fact that Bitnami has preconfigured everything on the server software stack for you.